# Merge more than 100 json files to one file using java code

Tags: java, arrays, variables, merge

I try to put more than 100 similar jsonArray to one file, but I cannot resolve how I can name jsonArray`s name as variable in "for cycle" in java.
Please, help me. All questions that I found here about 2-3 jsonArrays with final names.

```
for (int j=1; j<10; j++) {
    

        //StringEntity json2 = new StringEntity("c:/test/test.txt");

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        String data="";
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
             new FileInputStream("c:/test1/jsonparser" + j +".json"), "UTF-8"));
            
            
            int i;
            while((i=br.read())!=-1)
            {
                stringBuffer.append((char)i);
            }
            data = stringBuffer.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                //LoggerUtil.printStackTrace(e);
        }
        finally{
            if(fileInputStream!=null){  
                fileInputStream.close();
            }
        }
      

       JSONTokener tokener1 = new JSONTokener(data);
       JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(tokener1);
     
       JSONArray sourceArray = new JSONArray(json1);
        JSONArray destinationArray = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length(); i++) {
        destinationArray.put(sourceArray.getJSONObject(i));
                }

        String s3 = destinationArray.toString();

        System.out.println(s3);
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data: What is your input and was is your expected and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the requirement right, you want to merge a large number of single JSON files into one large String that you want to parse later.

For my understanding, this should work like this:

```java
final var joiner = new StringJoiner( ", ", "{ array : [", "]}";
for( var i = 0; i < maxFiles; ++i )
{
  final var path = Path.of( "c:/test1/jsonparser%d.json".formatted( i ) );
  joiner.add( Files.readString( path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
}
final var combinedJSON = joiner.toString();
```

If you want to have a kind of `struct` instead of an array, that may look like this:

```java
final var joiner = new StringJoiner( "}, {", "{", "}";
for( var i = 0; i < maxFiles; ++i )
{
  final var path = Path.of( "c:/test1/jsonparser%d.json".formatted( i ) );
  joiner.add( "object%d : %s".formatted( i, Files.readString( path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) );
}
final var combinedJSON = joiner.toString();
```

And of course, I omitted any error handling …

---

Ok, let's fix your code:

```java
JSONArray destinationArray = new JSONArray();
for( int j = 1; j < 10; ++j ) 
{
  String data = "";
  // try-with-resources makes things easier …
  try( final var br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( "c:/test1/jsonparser" + j +".json" ), "UTF-8" ) );
  {
    // StringBuilder is more efficient than StringBuffer in this case
    final StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    // Of course you can read a file like this, but you also shoot you in the foot …
    int i;
    while( ( i = br.read() ) != -1 )
    {
      stringBuffer.append( (char) i );
    }
    data = stringBuffer.toString();
  }
  catch( IOException e ) // NEVER catch java.lang.Exception!
  {
    // We log the failure for this file and try the next one …
    //LoggerUtil.printStackTrace(e);
    // Not nice, but can be done this way
  }
  JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener( data );
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject( tokener );
  destinationArray.put( json );
}
      
String s3 = destinationArray.toString();
System.out.println(s3);
```

But why parsing the JSON files when simple operations on `String` would do the job, too? Only when it could be possible that the input files are not valid JSON, it makes sense to parse them before merging, because at a failure you know which file was broken.